# Prove the inequality for PDF which non decreasing in interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am working on the following problem.

Given a pdf $f$ that is non-decreasing in the interval $ a \leq x \leq b $, show that for any $s>0$ 
              $\int^b_{a}{x^{2s}f(x)}dx \geq  \frac{b^{2s+1}-a^{2s+1}}{(2s+1)(b-a)} \int^b_{a}{f(x)dx}$.

I don't understand. how to start...can any one provide me solution of that problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For every nondecreasing real-valued functions $u$ and $v$ and every probability measure $\mu$ on the real line $\mathbb R$, $$\int_\mathbb R uv\mathrm d\mu\geqslant\int_\mathbb R u\mathrm d\mu\cdot\int_\mathbb R v\mathrm d\mu.$$

Comment: Hi @Did - Does that inequality have a name or might you have some reference for it?

Comment: Name: Coupling inequality. Reference: *The coupling method* by Lindvall (which will give you much more). Proof: one line.