# Almost a variant of coupling inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-theory, inequality

Given a pdf $f$ that is non decreasing in the interval $a \le x \le b$, show that for any $s>0$,
$\int_{a}^{b} x^{2s}f(x) dx \ge \frac{b^{2s+1}-a^{2s+1}}{(2s+1)(b-a)}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$
I saw the post [Prove the inequality for PDF which non decreasing in interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889777/prove-the-inequality-for-pdf-which-non-decreasing-in-interval) which states that coupling inequality kills it. But I have a problem here, suppose $a,b<0$, then $x^{2s}$ is decreasing, in that case it does not satisfy the non-decreasing criterion.
Any other way to prove this?

Comment: Guess that it's implicit that $a,b>0$. For instance $b^{2s+1}$ doesn't make sense if $b<0$ and $s$ is not integer.

Comment: didn't get you why that does not make sense?

Comment: How do you calculate $(-3)^{2.5}$?